# Php rest service not returning correct responses

Tags: php, rest

I've recently wanted to use a library, that is only available in Php (**[austinb/gameq](https://github.com/Austinb/GameQ)**)

As I really dont know much about Php, to be able to use it with my other webservices (.Net core), I've decided that best way would be to just host it as its own Rest service.

I've tried using **[marcj/php-rest-service](https://github.com/marcj/php-rest-service)** but to no avail, all responses I get are 200(Ok), even when an endpoint is not correct. No errors in both browser and local consoles.

I use `php -S localhost:8888 index.php` to start it. Am I missing something?

**index.php**

```
<?php 
include 'vendor/autoload.php';

use RestService\Server;

require_once("restGameQ.php");
Server::create('/GameQ', 'GameQRestApi\GameQApi')
    ->collectRoutes()
->run();
```

**restGameQ.php**

```
<?php
namespace GameQRestApi;

class GameQApi {
    /**
    * Dummy response check.
    */
    public function getHi(){
        return 'Hi!';
    }

    /**
    * Gets state of server defined in server.json
    */
    public function getServersState(){
        $GameQ = new \GameQ\GameQ();
        $GameQ->addServersFromFiles('servers.json');
        return $GameQ->process();
    }

    /**
    * Checks state of the server under this address (accepted types consult: https://github.com/Austinb/GameQ/tree/v3/src/GameQ/Protocols )
    */
    public function postCheckServer($type, $ip, $port){
        $GameQ = new \GameQ\GameQ();
        $GameQ->addServer([
            'type' => $type,
            'host' => $ip+':'+$port,
        ]);
        return $GameQ->process();
    }
}
```

P.S. I've really wanted to use **[peachpiecompiler/peachpie](https://github.com/peachpiecompiler/peachpie)** but they dont support yet stream_select that is required by the lib.

Comment: update: peachpie does support `stream_select` since `0.9.600` (december 2019)

Comment: Yeah, it's a fix for an issue I myself reported. Didn't have time to test it though.
https://github.com/peachpiecompiler/peachpie/issues/590

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I found that marcj/php-rest-service is an old repo, with many problems in newer PHP versions.

[ElementaryFramework/WaterPipe](https://github.com/ElementaryFramework) is a great, still supported and robust framework for your HTTP needs.